# Java generic method inheritance and override rules

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class, generic-method

I have an abstract class that has a generic method and I want to override the generic method by substituting specific types for the generic parameter. So in pseudo-code I have the following:

```
public abstract class GetAndParse {
  public SomeClass var;

  public abstract <T extends AnotherClass> void getAndParse(T... args);
}

public class Implementor extends GetAndParse {
  // some field declarations

  // some method declarations

  @Override
  public <SpecificClass> void getAndParse(SpecificClass... args) {
    // method body making use of args
  }
}
```

But for some reason I'm not allowed to do this? Am I making some kind of syntax error or is this kind of inheritance and overriding not allowed? Specifically I'm getting an error about `@Override` because the eclipse IDE keeps reminding me to implement `getAndParse`.

Here's how I want the above code to work. Somewhere else in my code there is a method that expects instances of objects that implement `GetAndParse` which specifically means that they have a `getAndParse` method that I can use. When I call `getAndParse` on that instance the compiler checks to see whether I have used specific instances of `T` in the proper way, so in particular `T` should extend `AnotherClass` and it should be `SpecificClass`.

Comment: pseudo code too abstract, need more info

Comment: Using `public abstract <T extends AnotherClass> void getAndParse(Args... args);` makes no sense. What is the type parameter good for? How should the compiler determine its actual value and where should it use it?

Comment: Could you get us a complete example, which is in fact compilable (apart from the problematic error) and produces the error you mentioned?

Comment: @maaartinus: You're right I've changed the methods to make specific use of the generic type.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What we are having here is two different methods with individual type parameters each.

```
public abstract <T extends AnotherClass> void getAndParse(Args... args);
```

This is a method with a type parameter named T, and bounded by `AnotherClass`, meaning each subtype of `AnotherClass` is allowed as a type parameter.

```
public <SpecificClass> void getAndParse(Args... args)
```

This is a method with a type parameter named `SpecificClass`, bounded by `Object` (meaning each type is allowed as a type parameter). Do you really want this?

Is the type parameter used inside `Args`? I think the problem would be there.

---

The meaning of

```
public abstract <T extends AnotherClass> void getAndParse(T... args);
```

is that the **caller** of the method can decide with which type parameter he wants to call the method, as long as this is some subtype of `AnotherClass`. This means that in effect the method can be called with any objects of type `AnotherClass`.

Since the caller can decide the type parameter, you can't in a subclass narrow down the parameter type to `SpecificClass` - this would not be an implementation of the method, but another method with same name (overloading).

Maybe you want something like this:

```
public abstract class GetAndParse<T extends AnotherClass> {
  public SomeClass var;

  public abstract void getAndParse(T... args);
}

public class Implementor extends GetAndParse<SpecificClass> {
  // some field declarations

  // some method declarations

  @Override
  public void getAndParse(SpecificClass... args) {
    // method body making use of args
  }
}
```

Now the `getAndParse` method implements the parent class' method.

Comment: I don't want a type parameter. I want the compiler to check and make sure that `SpecificClass` is an extension of `AnotherClass`.

Answer (score 22):

You are seeing this problem because of the concept called "Erasure" in Java Generics.
Java uses "erasure" to support backward compatibility. i.e Java code which did not use generics.

**Erasure Procedure:**
The compiler will first do a type checking and then it will remove(erase) all the type parameters as much as possible, and also insert TypeCasting where ever necessary.

example:

```
public abstract <T extends AnotherClass> void getAndParse(T paramAnotherClass);
```

will become

```
public abstract void getAndParse(AnotherClass paramAnotherClass);
```

In class "Implementor.java",

The code

```
public <SpecificClass> void getAndParse(T paramAnotherClass)
```

will become

```
public void getAndParse(SpecificClass paramAnotherClass){  }
```

the compiler will see that you have not implemented the abstract method correctly.
There is a type mismatch between the abstract method and the implemented method. This is why you are seeing the error.

More details can be found here.
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/12/02/explorations.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *override* to specific type T because there is in fact (at the bytecode level if you wish) only one method `getAndParse` because of type erasure (see other answer):

```
public abstract void getAndParse(AnotherClass... args); // (1)
```

For every type of T, the same method is used.

You can *overload* it (I think):

```
public void getAndParse(SpecificClass... args); // (2)
```

but this will not a different method from (1) ant it will *not* be called by generic code:

```
T x = whatever;
object.getAndParse(x); // Calls (1) even if T is derived from SpecificClass
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not valid. What would happen if someone with a `GetAndParse` reference called it with *a different* class extending `AnotherClass`?

Comment: I don't understand why this is a problem. I have an implementor that extends `GetAndParse` and fixes the type of `T` to `SpecficClass` which the compiler checks to make sure extends `AnotherClass` then in my code when I have an instance of `Implementor` and call `getAndParse` with a type that doesn't match `SpecificClass` I should get an error.

Comment: @davidk01: The contract provided by GetAndParse say that everyone implementing it must do so for any type extending AnotherClass. Given `GetAndParse foo = new Implementor();` you must able to call `foo.getAndParse` for any extension of AnotherClass - If the compiler didn't enforce this, you could just as well use Object, the point of generics is to ensure compile-time type safety

Answer (score 1):

That becomes a nonsense when someone has a reference to type GetAndParse and tries to call the getAndParse method.  If Cat and Dog extend AnotherClass.  I should expect to be able to call GetAndParse#getAndParse with either a Cat or a Dog.  But the implementation has tried to restrict it and make it less compatible!

Comment: That is the reason that what you want to do is impossible, I apologize if I framed it in a way you don't like.  Compile time generics are not capable of enforcing that for you.  How is the compiler to know what subclass will be there at runtime?  It's entirely possible the implementor is returned by a factory interface and comes from a different library you're not even compiling against!  Narrowing of the type parameter cannot be checked for safety at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

**Static method can't override**

```
class Vehicle{
static void park(int location){
    System.out.println("Vehicle parking..");
}}

class Car extends  Vehicle{
@Override //error
void park(int location) { //error
    System.out.println("Car Parking..");
}}
```

**Private method can't override**

```
class Vehicle{
private void park(int location){
    System.out.println("Vehicle parking..");
}
void callPark(){
    park(100);
}}

class Car extends  Vehicle{
//@Override
void park(int location) {
    System.out.println("Car Parking..");
}}

class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vehicle v1=new Car();
   v1.callPark();
}}
```

**Final method can't override**

```
class Vehicle{
final void park(int location){
    System.out.println("Vehicle parking..");
}}

class Car extends  Vehicle{
//@Override
void park(int location) { //error
    System.out.println("Car Parking..");
}}
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive by what you mean with your answer? I could guess that you're listing ways where Override doesn't work. But can you give an introduction why this has anything to do with this question? Please [edit] your answer to make it better.