# How to override a generic method

Tags: java, generics, overriding

Generic method :

```
public <T> void foo(T t);
```

Desired overridden method :

```
public void foo(MyType t);
```

What is the java syntax to achieve this?

Comment: Is T constrained by the class? As in, is the method enclosed in some generic `class Example<T> { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better design is.

```
interface Generic<T> {
    void foo(T t);
}

class Impl implements Generic<MyType> {
    @Override
    public void foo(MyType t) { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to do something like this :

```
abstract class Parent {

    public abstract <T extends Object> void foo(T t);

}

public class Implementor extends Parent {

    @Override
    public <MyType> void foo(MyType t) {

    }
}
```

A similar question was answered here as well : [Java generic method inheritance and override rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346847/java-generic-method-inheritance-and-override-rules)

Comment: Do you understand that `MyType` here is generic parameter name, not name of existing class?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Base {
    public <T> void foo(T t);
}

class Derived implements Base {
    public <T> void foo(T t){

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think is this related here ?

Comment: Probably he wants to have specific implementation in overriden method.

Comment: @Snehal Masne of course he can put any implementation inside.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension (in example: how does your code work).

Comment: @reporter Isn't it obvious