# Java Inheritance. Parent has list of parent, child must have list of childs. How?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to achieve the next:

Parent:

```
public class Animal {
    private List<Animal> relatives;

    public List<Animal> getRelatives() {
        return relatives;
    }

    public void setRelatives(List<Animal> relatives) {
        this.relatives = relatives;
    }
}
```

Child:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    private List<Dog> relatives;

    public List<Dog> getRelatives() {
        return relatives;
    }

    public void setRelatives(List<Dog> relatives) {
       this.relatives = relatives;
    }
}
```

But for some reason, I get errors that the methods are clashing. Is this even possible with inheritance, without using generic types?

Comment: maybe that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346847/java-generic-method-inheritance-and-override-rules

Comment: This design would violate Liskov substitution principle. `Animal.getRelatives()` should return a `List<Animal>`, so by Liskov substitution principle, `dog.getRelatives().add(new Cat())` must be ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need to override/duplicate anything in the child class.

```
class Animal<Relative extends Animal<?>> {
  private List<? extends Relative> relatives;

  public List<? extends Relative> getRelatives() {
    return relatives;
  }

  public void setRelatives(List<? extends Relative> relatives) {
    this.relatives = relatives;
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal<Dog> {}
```

Comment: Why `<? extends Relative>`, rather than just `<Relative>`?

Comment: `class Dog extends Animal<String>` seems legit

Comment: `class Animal<R extends Animal> { private List<R> relatives;` ?

Comment: Gonna try this out on my work tommorow. Is Relative a conincidental java class, or does it function as T?

Comment: @dendimiiii It functions as `T`.

Comment: @AndyTurner to allow to pass, let's say, a `List<DomesticDog>` to `setRelatives` (`DomesticDog` extends `Dog`)

Comment: @VictorGubin I am not sure it's right. It would be possible to write `class Dog extends Animal<Cat> {}`

Comment: @Michael how would you bound it? `Relative extends Animal<?>` doesn't look right to me since we put no restrictions on who could be a relative to an animal. I came up with `class Animal<Parent extends Animal, Relative extends Parent>` which would reject things like `class Dog extends Animal<Dog, Cat>` but I am not sure if it's always OK.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko The first one is almost right, but you are using the raw type. It should be `Animal<Relative extends Animal<?>>`

Answer (score 2):

You could use generic and hold `relatives` in parent class. Additionally, you should aware of holding of unexpected modification:

```
public class Animal<T extends Animal<?>> {

    private final List<T> relatives = new ArrayList<>();

    public final List<T> getRelatives() {
        return relatives.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() : Collections.unmodifiableList(relatives);
    }

    public final void addRelative(T relative) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(relative);
        relatives.add(relative);
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal<Dog> {

    // just for test
    public List<Dog> getRelativesDogs() {
        return super.getRelatives();
    }

    // just for test
    public void addRelativeDog(Dog dog) {
        super.addRelative(dog);
    }

}
```

Comment: `relatives.add(relative)` won't compile.

Comment: I am not sure if `T extends Animal<?>` is correct since you can write `class Dog extends Animal<Cat> {}`

Comment: I am thinking of `class Animal<Parent extends Animal, Relative extends Parent>` which would reject things like class `Dog extends Animal<Dog, Cat>` but I am not sure if it's always OK.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I think this is not what should care about.